# local settings can not find the app

Tags: django, django-settings

Everytime I try to run the app, or migrate my database, it throws this error. My IDE, although, helps me run the app because the configurations seem to be correct but bash fails to run any of the Django commands.

This is the error that I get:

```
File "/Users/angy/settings/projname_conf/settings.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyup.generic_settings import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyup'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know pyup, but that's what i found:

To install pyup, run:

```
$ pip install pyupio
```

https://github.com/pyupio/pyup

Comment: pyup is not a package. It is the name of my project ;) Nevertheless, I managed to fix it. There was an expected configuration issue. The python path was incorrect. I added DJANGO_MODULE_SETTINGS and the correct PYTHONPATH to the activate file